# kdb primary key unique

Tags: primary-key, kdb

Why there is no uniqueness constraint in kdb primary keys? Below I can create two rows with primary key column sym

```
kt:([sym:`a`b`c`c]name:`alpha`beta`gamma`zeta);
kt

©¬ sym  name
a   alpha
b   beta
c   gamma
c   zeta
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [kx wiki on keyed tables](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#841-keyed-table)

> Keys should be unique but (sadly) this is not enforced. As we have already noted, dictionary creation does not enforce key uniqueness. A value row associated with a duplicate key is not accessible via key lookup, but it can be retrieved via a select on the key column.

Here’s the [kx wiki reference for non-unique keys and values](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/5_Dictionaries/#516-non-unique-keys-and-values)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will find that kdb won't hold your hand - if you need rule enforcement you have to set it up yourself.

You can use a `u#` (unique) attribute to enforce key uniqueness:

```
q)kt:([sym:`a`b`c]name:`alpha`beta`gamma);
q)update `u#sym from `kt
`kt
q)`kt insert (`c;`zeta)
'insert
  [0]  `kt insert (`c;`zeta)
           ^
q)`kt insert (`d;`zeta)
,3
q)kt
sym| name
---| -----
a  | alpha
b  | beta
c  | gamma
d  | zeta
```